# Not to update the subview with superview alpha value

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

My question is when i added a view as subview to Root view.When i changed the alpha value of root view same is occurring in subview also.Actually i don't need the updating in subview.Is there any solution to do like that.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This will change only the alpha of the root view, not the others

```
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];
```

Comment: indeed that is awesome. this should be at the very top of the google search. seriously

Answer (score 9):

Building on the answer by @shabbirv, one can also use IB's color picker

[image: color picker]

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to change the structure of your views. Instead of laying your subviews out on the roots view, create a layer ontop of your root view, but still add the subviews to the root. When changing the layer's alpha it won't effect the subviews. Example structure below.

Your current structure:

```
RootView->Subviews //Changing RootView alpha effects Subviews.
```

Needed Structure:

```
RootView->View->Subviews(Still Added to RootView) //Changing alpha of Layer doesn't effect subviews.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: good but exactly not suits to my problem. I have a root view. I want to add a view as like alert view to root view.And when i added the subview to root view the root view should look like transparent and elements should not accessed in that view.I want to enable interaction with subview.

Comment: @skram: by layer, did you mean another view?

Comment: Yes, Sorry. I will re-phrase it. A `UIView` acting as a layer between  the root and subviews.

Answer (score 1):

This will also solve this by changing root view color by below way, this will not affect the subview.

```
[rootView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7]];
```