# Alpha value for NSView subviews

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsview

I am working on Cocoa on OSX 10.9

When I change the alpha value to some view it also affects all the subviews.
What do I do, so that alpha value becomes applicable only to that specific view and not its subviews.

Same question has been asked for Cocoa Touch [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892535/not-to-update-the-subview-with-superview-alpha-value) but it is not applicable to Appkit.
Can anyone suggest a solution for Cocoa so that it works for NSView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS how to make subview of a transparent view opaque?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081155/ios-how-to-make-subview-of-a-transparent-view-opaque)

Comment: @JoeBlow Not a duplicate. NSView does not have a background selector

Comment: Hey michael!  NO big deal, but a number of answers/comments on that question suggest the same as the accepted answer here, which is the way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of an approach that'll work with your current view hierarchy.
**What I'd do instead:**

Use an **additional, common super view** and leave it be.

Next add **two chains of subviews** to that master view -

- one you'll want to dim or reduce alpha value for,
- a second one for subviews that'll stay 100% opaque all the time.