# iOS how to make subview of a transparent view opaque?

Tags: ios

I have a view as the subview of another view, then I set the alpha value of the father view something like 0.5, but this also makes the subview transparent even when its alpha value is set to 1. So how can I make the subview non-transparent(opaque) when its father view has an alpha value less than 1?

Comment: I'm new here so much appreciated if anyone could tell me why my question is voted down? Then I can avoid such issue in my questions in the future.

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks for such a detailed reply!

Comment: Don't forget the simple solution is, just don't make B a child of that view A. Make B a child of a "holder" which holds both, but have B on top.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The closest you're going to get is `colorWithAlphaComponent:`. Using something like the following, you can set the alpha component of the parent view's background, and it won't affect subviews.

```
[yourSuperview setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the parent view to 0.5 all the subviews will also go to 0.5 or less. You'll have to come up with a different design approach.

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 4.2**

```
    self.yoursuperview.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method worked for me.

```
superView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Now that alpha property of superview is not altered, it won't affect the alpha of its subview. Hence, subviews will be opaque(if you have a background color for it).

Answer (score 0):

You should have two designs for the parent view. One would be the "enabled" design, showing it as it is and the other would be the "disabled" design, which would contain transparent background.

You cannot do this with alpha, as subviews inherit the alpha. If

parent.alpha = x

and

view.alpha = y,

then the real alpha of the view will be:

x * y

Comment: Why so complicated..?? Check out the other answers for a better approach

Answer (score 0):

I think, You have create View by Storyboard. I had already face this problem. Find the below code, this is correct in my case.

```
[MyParentView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6]];
```

Hope, This may help you.